# "Failed to execute child process (No such file or directory)" when calling gnome-terminal subprocess in Python 3

Tags: python, subprocess, child-process, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write a program that opens a gnome-terminal window and executes a python file in it.

When I call the `gnome-terminal` subprocess with the subprocess module like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python3 '+filename])
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute child process "python3 /home/user/Documents/test.py” (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried to cd to the directory `/home/user/Documents/test.py` first and then run the file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from os import system
system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 %s\"'"%filename)
```

Add other commands using a semicolon:

```
system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 %s; [second command]\"'")
```

Comment: I downvoted because you just switched to using `system` rather than `subprocess`, and that doesn't seem to address the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute the literal command `python3 /home/user/Documents/test.py` which obviously doesn't exist on your system.

When you type that line in a shell, the shell will split it on spaces and in the end it will call `python3` with `/home/user/Documents/test.py` as argument.

When using `subprocess.call`, you have to do the splitting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to pass your filename as another element in the array. I don't have gnome-terminal, but I replicated your issue with plain `sh`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python3', filename])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this  (i assume that python3 is set in PATH)

```
from subprocess import Popen

command="gnome-terminal -x python3"+filename

proc=Popen(command)
```

if this not works 
then try to run your python file first , and see if it works or not

```
python filename
```